# Can I change configuration (application.conf) of production without recompile?

Tags: configuration, playframework, production

I have a play 2.3.3 application which I deploy in production mode to server. I want to change configuration parameters without recompile and redeploy. Is it possible?

I tried to manipulate the file on the server after what I restarted the app, but it seems it doesn't catch up the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify an alternate config file and modify that one: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration